# Derive Locale from formatted string

Tags: java

I'm facing the following problem: From an external service I'm getting formatted number data which can be formatted using different locales:

```
1.234,00 (de_DE)
1,234.12 (en_US)
```

What's the best way to programmatically derive the Locale that has been used to format the String so I can parse the value to its primitive type?

Comment: I was thinking about brute-force parsing the string using all currently available locales one after the other (maybe pre-ordered by likelihood), but that doesn't seem very good...

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to avoid throwing NumberFormatExceptions is to use regular expressions to detect the locale. From your example:

```
String sDE = "1.234,00"; // (de_DE)
String sEN = "1,234.12"; // (en_US)

Pattern patternEN = Pattern.compile("[0-9],[0-9].[0-9]");
Pattern patternDE = Pattern.compile("[0-9].[0-9],[0-9]");

System.out.println(" DE - EN : " + patternEN.matcher(sDE).find());
System.out.println(" EN - EN : " + patternEN.matcher(sEN).find());
System.out.println(" DE - DE : " + patternDE.matcher(sDE).find());
System.out.println(" EN - DE : " + patternDE.matcher(sEN).find());
```

Gives the following result:

```
 DE - EN : false
 EN - EN : true
 DE - DE : true
 EN - DE : false
```

You may need to refine the regex for a fully working environment.

Comment: that goes into the right direction, but i'd like to have something generic, so that i can also get French locales for example. Or Chinese.